# DB2: How to display data in a normalized table from other tables?

Tags: sql, database, join, db2

DB2 v10.1 database on WINDOWS 7

I have three tables:

1.table Rase

```
     id  Rases   Length
     1   Moscow  300
     2   Krasno   400
```

2.table Plan

```
    id  Name    Date
    1   ТУ124   10.12.1987
    2   Ан24    10.01.1998
```

3.table Kril

```
     ID      COLOR            WEIGH    
      1      green            124,56
      2      blue             187,40
      3      black            231,00
```

Need to display data in a normalized table ALL_D, as presented below: ID - Primary Key Plan - a reference to Plan.Name Kril - a reference to Kril.Color Race - a reference to Race.Rases Time_Start-departure time (CURRENT TIMESTAMP)

1. table ALL_D

```
     ID   Name  Color     Rases        Time_Start
     1   ТУ124  Green     Moscow    2011-10-25-19.12.30.000000
     2   АН24   Blue      Krasno    2011-10-27-17.14.30.000000
```

I do not understand how to perform this task.

Comment: Without understanding _exactly_ what these tables are being used for, it's hard to tell, but I seriously doubt that `ALL_D` is _normalized_.  I rather suspect it would be **de** normalized.

Comment: I agree with you. But the job was written in the table ALL_D normalized.
Normalized table should look like this: **1 Plan.id Kril.id Rase.id current timestamp**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic join query.

```
insert into all_d
    select rase.id, plan.name, kril.color, rase.rases, 
           current timestamp as time_start
        from rase
        join plan on plan.id = rase.id
        join kril on kril.id = rase.id
```

`join` is the same as `inner join`--only ids that are common to all three tables will be returned.

Update: also added the insert into result table.